# Getting error when trying to round available RAM

Tags: python

I am trying to make my console show how much available RAM I have. When I first tried, it gave me lots of digits after the decimal, and I was going to try to round that. So I tried this:

```py
import psutil

available = str(round(psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory())).total
```

When I run it, I get the following error.

```
File "main.py", line 32, in task
    available = str(round(psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory())).total
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'svmem'
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Well, a `TypeError` is an `Error` that has to do with the `Type` of some values. The error happens because you try to `/` (divide) between a `int` (integer) and `svmem` (the thing that you get by calling `psutil.virtual_memory()`, which is `unsupported`. I assume you were expecting the denominator to be an integer as well, specifically, the result of `psutil.virtual_memory().total`. To fix this, you should look carefully at where the parentheses are in your code, and think carefully about where they should be, according to the order of the steps you want the code to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that in your division `psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory()`, the right part is of type svmem, and the left part is of type int. Python doesn't know how to divide an int (number) by a svmem (a custom psutil class), which is the result of calling `psutil.virtual_memory()`, and it's telling you that. The left side is an int because you called `psutil.virtual_memory().available` which is a number.

This is happening because your `.total` is placed after all the parentheses, so it's calling `.total` on the result of the whole operation.

Try this instead:

```
available = str(round(psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory().total))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the correction for your code.

```
available = str(round(psutil.virtual_memory().available * 100 / psutil.virtual_memory().total))
```

To print the result:

```
print(available)
```

However the output will not give you the correct available ram information. To display available ram in MB format, you can use:

```
available = psutil.virtual_memory().available >> 20
print(available)
```

To display in GB format:

```
available = psutil.virtual_memory().available >> 30
print(available)
```