# How to get available memory (ram) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

I couldn't find an answer in the internet or stackoverflow but I have tried this method but it's not good one

```
from os import popen
output  = popen("free -ht").read()
print(output[154:-90])
```

```
output: 2.4G
```

Is there any python library for this or at least a solution.

Comment: See [Getting error when trying to round available RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697486/getting-error-when-trying-to-round-available-ram?r=SearchResults&s=1|102.6191) for how to get current ram. So, basically use `import psutil psutil.virtual_memory().available`.

Comment: Which "kind" of available memory (there are many), and on which OS?

Comment: You can use this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615591/available-and-used-system-memory-in-python

Comment: There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718449/determine-free-ram-in-python?r=SearchResults&s=9|53.5024)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Available and used System Memory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615591/available-and-used-system-memory-in-python)